# Mismatch in values calculated by scipy.integrate

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, math, scipy, integral

While using integrate in the scipy module, I notice that the values of the integral do not match with the expected value (which I computed by hand).

I have a simple function as follows:

```
import math
def integrand(x, L):
    return (math.cos(sc.pi * x / L))**2
     

L=10
I = quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(L))

I = 0.9677446418943196 # from scipy
```

But theoretically, the result should be 0.5519233944327677. I am quite confused as to why discrepancy exists.

The integral I am trying to find is as follows:

[image]

Comment: The true value is `0.9677446`

Answer (score 2):

The scipy is correct. Your calculation is incorrect:

[image]

Note that the Decimal given matches the one obtained by `scipy`. This question is best suited for stackexchange.